# A* Pathfinding Algorithm In C#, Implement Ladder System

Tags: c#, path-finding, a-star

I have already implemented A star path-finding in C# language via grid based system. But I am trying to make a system which will use a ladder to move to a shortest distance if there is any ladder available in that shortest. But i am without any clue how to do that , i have searched online and read a lot of posts still i am confused how to do that , so it will be much helpful to me how to add the ladder feature in a A star path-finding algorithm.

[Image](https://proxy.spigotmc.org/794fd75f28021cb0576a876b62f60a9ed22e21ae?url=http%3A%2F%2Fpuu.sh%2Fh6CKi%2Fccf9eed584.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think of your ladders as vertices in your graph. Then you just need to apply A*, which is a best-first search. This is a well-documented algorithm. For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm):

> A* is an informed search algorithm, or a best-first search, meaning
>   that it solves problems by searching among all possible paths to the
>   solution (goal) for the one that incurs the smallest cost (least
>   distance travelled, shortest time, etc.), and among these paths it
>   first considers the ones that appear to lead most quickly to the
>   solution. It is formulated in terms of weighted graphs: starting from
>   a specific node of a graph, it constructs a tree of paths starting
>   from that node, expanding paths one step at a time, until one of its
>   paths ends at the predetermined goal node.

Comment: could you be more specific. my code for A* algorithm works fine but have no idea how to do for ladders in 3D. (Edited my post with a image which i found from some blogs).
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user2069785, if a ladder unit has a standard length, then you can think about your 3D space like a graph where each (x, y, z) point MIGHT be a node. Such a point is a Node if and only if you can reach it through a ladder. So, the ladders are the vertices. So, if (x, y, z) points are nodes and ladders are vertices, then you just have to have a representation which converts your raw data into A*-absorbable input.

Comment: how do I represent ladder into vertices. can you help me giving me an accurate direction how to solve my problem.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Perman, let us consider the example of two points: (1, 0, 0) and (1, 1, 0). If there is a ladder between the two, then both are nodes, so you need to store them as nodes. And you need a neighbours collection for your Node representation, where you will store the neighbouring nodes. For both nodes you will store the other as neighbour. That is the fundament of your task. If you add a third node, it will be a neighbour to at least another node and that other node will be neighbour to your new node as well.

Comment: @Perman, finding the closest path from a point to a location where you do not have a ladder yet means that you traverse your nodes by visiting the neighbours and checking whether the number of neighbours is 8. If yes, then you are not on the edge yet. If not, you have found a new element. The greedy criteria of A* would be the Manhattan distance between the start point and each new point in the nodes of your current node. Basically, that's all what you need to know before you start to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. now i get it.

Comment: @Perman, you are welcome. Let me know about the result of your current effort and if this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it.